# access variable value from view within a django class

Tags: python, django, class, view

I currently have a class **urldata.py**, with a loop:

```
from Scanner.views import Processinitialscan
    for element in elements:
        dbInsert = PathsOfDomain(pathToScan=element.attrs["href"],FKtoTld=Processinitialscan.)
        dbInsert.save()
```

I have a **view.py** with a variable `EnteredDomainRowID`, that I want to use in the `class` above:

```
def Processinitialscan(request):
    EnteredDomainRowID = GetEnteredDomainObjects.pk
```

I've been trying:

```
FKtoTld=Processinitialscan.EnteredDomainRowID
```

in :

```
dbInsert = PathsOfDomain(pathToScan=element.attrs["href"],FKtoTld=Processinitialscan.)
```

but, this doesn't seem to work.

**My question**, how do I access the value from the variable `EnteredDomainRowID` from `views.py` within my `class` urldata.py for the variable `dbInsert` (as shown above) ?

Additionally, I cannot seem to be able to import `views.py` into a `urldata.py` , is this not possible?

Any help is really, really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: do you want `Processinitialscan` to be a class and `EnteredDomainRowID` be a class attribute?

Comment: No, processInitialScan is a view, within view.py . I basically need to grab the value of EnteredDomainRowID (within views.py) and use it within urldata.py . Does that make sense

Comment: Well, it doesn't make any sense. Django view is controller for HTTP request. If you were instantiating your class in a view than you could pass `EnteredDomainRowID` to it. Please, describe your workflow. How do you intend to use class from `urldata.py`?

Comment: Why can't you just pass the value to the function in urldata.py when you call it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman - please elaborate. It is not allowing me to import views.py into urldata.py via from Scanner.views import Processinitialscan

Comment: But why would you want to do that? It's the view that is called by the request handler, so the view should import urldata and then call the function inside it, passing the value.

Comment: @DanielRoseman can you show me what you mean here via code? Specifically the call the function inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not the way python works `EnteredDomainRowID` is not a property of your function object, but it is a local variable to the function.

You could pretty easily convert this to a [class based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/), which will allow you to easily access the classes attributes.

Comment: Based on your last point, what is the best practice in this instance?

Comment: @CodeTalk update with link, django docs will do much better justice than I can

Comment: is class based view best practice?

Comment: @CodeTalk not necessarily, django allows you to use function based or classed based, thats not the issue. Class based are just classes. YOu can set a class attribute and access it like you are trying to do in your example

Comment: Can you give me an example of setting class attribute and accessing it?

Comment: I'm not completely certain where to go from here, but thanks for the explanation